# Pressing Escape in VS Code Interactive (IPython) deletes the cell. How can I disable this?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython, python-interactive

I normally write code in a python script (`.py`-file) divided into cells (with `# %%`) and execute the cells or single lines of code in an interactive window to the right of the script.

The interactive window also has an interactive python shell at the bottom, which I use if I quickly want to write some code but not clutter my script. However, pressing **`Esc`** deletes the line. I can bring it back by pressing **`up arrow`**, but this only saves the last thing I typed, and I quite frequently press **`Esc`** accidentally due to using Vim at the same time.

Is it possible to disable **`Esc`** deleting the line? (Using Vim I can just press `dd` anyways...) I didn't find anything in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the shortcut key setting page (`Ctrl+K+S`) and enter `"Escape"` for search.

[image]

The settings in the page to achieve the effect you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in keybindings.json (which you can open with the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)):

```json
{
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "-interactive.input.clear",
},
```

This is more robust than unbinding from the keyboard shortcuts UI because it doesn't require keeping a when-clause in sync with that of the default keybinding. I.e. If the default keybinding's when-clause changes, you won't have to update your unbinding.

The default keybinding at the time of this writing is:

```json
{
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "interactive.input.clear",
    "when": "!LinkedEditingInputVisible && !accessibilityHelpWidgetVisible && !breakpointWidgetVisible && !editorHasMultipleSelections && !editorHasSelection && !editorHoverVisible && !exceptionWidgetVisible && !findWidgetVisible && !inSnippetMode && !isComposing && !markersNavigationVisible && !notificationToastsVisible && !parameterHintsVisible && !renameInputVisible && !selectionAnchorSet && !suggestWidgetVisible && activeEditor == 'workbench.editor.interactive'"
},
```